# Can't add http://localhost to DigitalOcean Spaces CORS Rules

Tags: cors, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

[image: Image Showing CORS Error]

As you can see from the image is it not currently possible to add `http://localhost` as a CORS rule.

Comment: just out of curiosity is this the problem with AWS S3 or we are talking about Digital ocean because in the attached screenshot as well as in the question header digital ocean it seems to me. But the tags are amazon web services.

Comment: The issue is with DigitalOcean. I'll edit the tags @samtoddler

Comment: in that case below answer is related is for AWS S3 service so it might not help.

Comment: It will, the DigitalOcean API is compatible with most Amazon S3 SDKs and functions. For example you can include Amazon's `aws-sdk` npm package in Node and it will work as a plug-and-play replacement when using DigitalOcean like so https://i.imgur.com/7ADSW42.png
You can read more about how they are interoperable here: https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/resources/s3-sdk-examples/

Comment: I had similar problem but solved it in a different way (updating `/etc/hosts`). https://stackoverflow.com/a/70315253/331655

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to fix this issue you must use a tool such as [s3cmd](https://s3tools.org/download). The easiest way to use this tool is by downloading the source. If you already have Python installed you can use the following commands to change DigitalOcean Spaces CORS configuration (requires python 2.7 or greater):

Note: You may also need to have [Gpg4win](https://www.gpg4win.org/) installed.

First download the source [from here](https://s3tools.org/download) and extract into any directory. Then run the following `commands` in that directory. You should also place your `cors.xml` config within this directory.

`python s3cmd --configure`

This is an example input for the config hosted on Amsterdam 3....

```
Access Key [YOUR_ACCESS_KEY]:
Secret Key [YOUR_SECRET_KEY]: 
S3 Endpoint [ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com]
DNS-style bucket+hostname:port template for accessing a bucket [%(bucket)s.ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com]:
Encryption password [password]:
```

`python s3cmd ls` - View all of your spaces

`python s3cmd setcors cors.xml s3://your-space-name-here` where `cors.xml` is a file in your working directory containing a standard cors configuration such as:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:4000</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

After running this final command you should now see in your DigitalOcean dashboard that your original CORS configuration has now been replaced with whatever configuration you saved to `cors.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Update, The Digital Ocean supports the localhost for now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add an entry to your local host file

127.0.0.1 local.test.com

and instead of:

localhost

use:

local.test.com