# CORS error : preflight missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, digital-ocean

here

I am trying to upload an Image to digitalOcean spaces via a react app and `aws-sdk/client-s3`
an error thrown in *console* says `Fetch failed loading: PUT MY-DO-SPACES-URL`
when incepting in *network* the error says : `cross error preflight Missing Allow Origin Header`
**NB:** I can upload an image from react-native app

`s3.js` file configuration

```
import { S3 } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const s3 = new S3({
    forcePathStyle: false, 
    endpoint: "https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com",
    region: "fra-1",
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: 'SECRET_KEY',
        secretAccessKey: 'ACCESS_KEY',
    }
});

export {s3};
```

`uploadImage` function

```
const uploadImage=async(file,id)=>{
    // file param from another function: event.target.files[0]
    if(file===null){
      console.log('please select file to upload')
    }
    else{
    const ImageURI = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    const ImageURL = await fetch(ImageURI)
    const ImageData = await ImageURL.blob()
    try{
      const uploadParams = {
        Bucket: 'digital-trader-spaces',
        Key: file.name,
        Body: file
      }
      const data = await s3.send(new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams))
      console.log(data)
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried to solve the issue from DigitalOcean Spaces Cors configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For digitalOcean you should config the cors using `s3cmd` I found the solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65523591/12863176
as an update for that answer you should fix the `cors.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```